# Prolog - Applying predicate with one fixed arguments over list

Tags: swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a program to solve the `n-queens problem`. To check if a queen attacks the other that are stored in a list `L` as lists with their coordinates (`[X,Y], etc...`), I wrote this piece of code :

```
safe_queens([X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]) :-
    X1 \== X2,
    Y1 \== Y2,
    abs(X1 - X2) \== abs(Y1 - Y2).

no_attack([_,_],[]).
no_attack(R0,[R|L]) :-
    maplist(safe_queens(R0,_),L)
    no_attack(R,L).
```

`safe_queens` checks if 2 queens cannot attack each other. I want to apply `safe_queens` for a queen `R0` over the rest of the list.

**How can I freeze R0 as one argument of the predicate, and let the other takes its value in the list `L` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by building another predicate to loop through the list and apply **safe_queens** on each element with **R0** Like This:

```
safe_queens([X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]) :-
    X1 \== X2,
    Y1 \== Y2,
    abs(X1 - X2) \== abs(Y1 - Y2).

mapThroughList(_,[]).
mapThroughList(R0,[H|T]):-
    safe_queens(R0,H),
    mapThroughList(R0,T).

no_attack([_,_],[]).
no_attack(R0,[R|L]) :-
    mapThroughList(R0,[R|L]),
    no_attack(R,L).
```

Also, this is a solution for the **N-Queen Problem** you can find this code:

```
solve(N,P) :-
    numlist(0,N,NL),
    permutation(NL,P),
    diagonals(NL,P,S,D),
    all_diff(S),
    all_diff(D). 

diagonals([],[],[],[]).
diagonals([X1|X],[Y1|Y],[S1|S],[D1|D]):- 
    S1 is X1 + Y1,
    D1 is X1- Y1,
    diagonals(X,Y,S,D).

all_diff([_]).
all_diff([X|Y]) :-
    \+member(X,Y),
    all_diff(Y).
```